# Sometimes json Array appears with images and sometimes empty array

Tags: android, json

Sometime json array appears with image url's and sometimes it is empty. I am using the following code where array with image url displaying data and image in listview but when array is empty then data is also not displaying. How can i slove this? Any answer will be appreciated

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
            try {
                JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

    // looping through all song nodes <song>

            for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);

                //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);


                JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                    String slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                    JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                    JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                    String url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);



        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, id);
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
        map.put(KEY_URL, url);


        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
            }   
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: "when array is empty then data is also not displaying." what does it means?

Comment: are you getting perfect response everytime? did you put your response log?

Comment: when json array url(image_url) is empty then the text(data) is not appearing( data will be present in json but it does not appear). IF the Json array displays some images then text and image both appear in listview @AndroidLearner

Comment: @RobinHood If images are present in json array then i am getting correct response. problem arise only when image is not present in array

Comment: @surya how you filling your json array? from where you getting response? what is `URL`?